Do higher beta energy particles produce a greater number of Cherenkov photons which are also more energetic?
I am trying to understand whether different radioisotope's beta emission results in different Cherenkov radiation spectra. In my understanding, a higher beta energy would mean it has a higher velocity and therefore produce higher energy Cherenkov photons.
And as for the number of photons produced by produced by a high vs low energy beta particle, my understanding is that a higher energy beta particle also produces more photons.
And so collectively, when we have 2 different beta emissions, the higher energy beta particle's Cherenkov radiation will have higher energy photons and also be more numerous. Would this be correct?

Cherenkov radiation really only has one parameter, $n$, dispersion notwithstanding.
The Frank-Tamm formula for the power spectrum is
$$
\frac{d^2E}{dxd\omega}
=\frac{q^2}{4\pi}\mu(\omega)\omega
\Big(
1-\frac{c^2}{v^2n^2(\omega)}
\Big)
$$
which does include dispersion and the magnetic permeability.
Now in normal detectors, $\mu=1$, and $n$ is approximately constant, so for a length $L$, the spectrum is:
$$
\frac{dE}{d\omega}
=\frac{q^2}{4\pi}\omega L
\Big(
1-\big(\frac 1{n\beta}\big)^2
\Big)
$$
with:
$$ \cos\theta = \frac 1 {n\beta}$$
that becomes:
$$
\frac{dE}{d\omega}
=\frac{q^2}{4\pi}\omega L \sin^2\theta
$$
You should plot that vs $\beta$, basically the power turns on with zero power at threshold ($\beta=1/n$)
and slowly approaches the peak value as $\beta\rightarrow 1$.
Now in gas Cherenkov detectors, e.g., air, you're dealing with 21 MeV electron, you get about 30 photons per meter (iirc) and $\beta$ is so close to one ($\gamma \approx 42$).
Maybe it's a little different in water, since there's still some wiggle room for smaller $\beta$.
See ring imaging Cherenkov detectors (RICH), since they measure cone angle and may provide velocity resolution (I think, I haven't built a Cherenkov since 1996)--the point though: cone angle, total number of photons, threshold, all depend on one parameter (in practice): $n$.

Thank you for the reply. Is there a layperson conclusion with regards to whether the beta energy has a positive correlation with the number of Cherenkov photons generated and the photon energy of the individual photons?

the answer is yes, but it's measurable through the cone angle. E.g., in my air example, you get from 0-30 photons with beta from threshold to c, but you detect them with a PMT that has 20% efficiency, so you get 0-6 photons. You can count the photons in a signal, but the standard deviation on the signal is 1 - 2.5, so can't relate that back to a beta with any confidence. In water, there are more photons, but the same principle applies.

Thanks a lot for that. How would I correlate it with the individual photon energy?
For example if I had a beta particle that is greater than 21 MeV, would there be more photons and also each photon should have more energy.
